# basic differential equation question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following statement arises in a proof I am reading, and I do not understand why this is:

Suppose $J$ is an open interval containing zero and $x: J \to W$ satisfies $x'(t)=f(x(t))$ and $x(0)=x_0$. Then by integration we have $x(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(x(s))\,ds. $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part - hope it helps

Comment: Ooooooohhh.  Thanks. I see it now.